# Problems with usage of while statement in R

Tags: r, while-loop

In my example, I want to merge two vectors into a single sorted vector. For this purpose I have decided to use while-loop. Here is my code:

```
merge_sort_func <- function(vect1,vect2){
    if((is.numeric(vect1) & is.numeric(vect2)) == FALSE){
        stop("The argument must be numeric!")
    }
    new_vect <- c(vect1,vect2)
    sort_vect <- numeric()
    i <- length(unique(new_vect))
    while(i != 0){
        sort_vect <- c(sort_vect,new_vect[which(x == min(new_vect))])
        new_vect <- new_vect[-which(x == min(new_vect))]
        i <- i-1
    }
    sort_vect
}
```

But in my case it doesn't work:

1. Sometimes it sorts vectors wrong (not in order)
2. Sometimes it yields this warning:

   > `In min(new_vect) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`

I think, that the main problem in my code is connected with `while` statement.
Can you tell me (or give me a hint) where am I wrong?

Comment: Whats is stopping you from using sort(new_vect)

Comment: Now i am learning the basics of R(loops).
So for now i want to construct programm without sort(), order() etc.

Comment: basic principle of learning any language is dont reinvent the wheel .sort is there for a good reason .

Comment: One could also say "the basic principle of learning a language is learning by doing". And "there is nothing new under the sun". I don't see what is so wrong with this approach. He is not trying to sort a vector. He is trying to write code to sort a vector. There is a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted didn't work (`x` was undefined). I think this is what you want. Just a couple of small changes:|

```
merge_sort_func <- function(vect1, vect2) {
    if ((is.numeric(vect1) & is.numeric(vect2)) == FALSE) {
        stop("The argument must be numeric!")
    }
    new_vect <- c(vect1, vect2)
    sort_vect <- numeric()
    i <- length(unique(new_vect))
    while (i != 0) {
        x <- min(new_vect)
        sort_vect <- c(sort_vect, new_vect[which(x == new_vect)])
        new_vect <- new_vect[ - which(x == new_vect)]
        i <- i - 1
    }
    sort_vect
}
```